# Laravel user login based on roles to different home page

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, user-roles

**The Scenario**

I have a simple application which has four main user roles.

- Admin (AdminController and Admin middleware file)
- Moderator (ModeratorController and Moderator middleware file)
- Agent (AgentController and Agent middleware file)
- Supplier(SupplierController and Supplier middleware file)

Each role has a separate **controller** and **middleware** as above. Every controller has index method which directs the controller to the respected home view.

**AdminController File**

```
class AdminController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('admin.home');
    }
}
```

*Note : same goes to other 3 controller files with respect to each role.*

**Middleware\Admin.php file**

```
use Auth;

class Admin
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        //return $next($request);

        if(auth::check() && Auth::user()->role == 1){
           return $next($request);
        }
        else {
           return redirect()->route('login');
        }
    }
}
```

*Note : same goes to other 3 middleware files with respect to each role.*

**Kernal.php**

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
        ...

        'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\Admin::class,
        'moderator' => \App\Http\Middleware\Moderator::class,
        'agent' => \App\Http\Middleware\Agent::class,
        'supplier' => \App\Http\Middleware\Supplier::class,
];
```

**routes\web.php**

```
Route::get('/admin', 'AdminController@index')->middleware('admin');
Route::get('/moderator', 'ModeratorController@index')->middleware('moderator');
Route::get('/agent', 'AgentController@index')->middleware('agent');
Route::get('/supplier', 'SupplierController@index')->middleware('supplier');
```

**\App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated**

```
class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {

        if ($guard == "admin" && Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect('/admin');
        }

        if ($guard == "moderator" && Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect('/moderator');
        }

        if ($guard == "agent" && Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect('/agent');
        }

        if ($guard == "supplier" && Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect('/supplier');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

**Finally my LoginController**

```
use Auth;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo;

    public function redirectTo()
    {
        switch(Auth::user()->role){
            case 1:
            $this->redirectTo = '/admin';
            return $this->redirectTo;
                break;
            case 2:
                    $this->redirectTo = '/moderator';
                return $this->redirectTo;
                break;
            case 3:
                $this->redirectTo = '/agent';
                return $this->redirectTo;
                break;
            case 4:
                    $this->redirectTo = '/supplier';
                return $this->redirectTo;
                break;
            default:
                $this->redirectTo = '/login';
                return $this->redirectTo;
        }
         
        // return $next($request);
    } 

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //$this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }
}
```

**QUESTIONS**

**Q1.** Is this the best way or rather most efficient way to achieve this?

**Q2.** Is this approach is secure enough to use in a real commercial application?

**Q3.** The routes work the way they are expected to work, For an instance if i go to    `localhost/login` and type relevant credentials it goes to the relevant home page based on the user role. And when i'm in `localhost/admin` and try to type and go to url `localhost/agent` it simply goes to the login `localhost/login` without logout the user.

[image]

However if the user doesn't want to try another login or rather want to go back to his dashboard, the app can't recognize the logged user's correct home to go back when click on the "Dashboard". When click, it redirects to the /home created by default `Auth` scaffolding which i have already removed from the app structure. Same apply to other user roles `eg; from localhost/agent to localhost/supplier, from localhost/moderator to localhost/admin, etc.`

What am i missing here?

*Please note that i started working with laravel few weeks back and still trying to figure the things out...*

Answer (score 0):

The middleware of `RedirectIfAuthenticated` is responsible for redirecting users that are currently authenticated in the site.

You should apply your logic in `redirectTo` method of `App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController` if you're using laravel/ui

Comment: About your second Question, in your middleware    if(auth::check() && Auth::user()->role == 1){ return $next($request); } else { //Logout user, Flush session then redirect return redirect()->route('login'); }