# multiple redirectTo for multiple role in laravel scaffolding ui

Tags: php, laravel

I have multiple role on my users: admin, guest, and receptionist

and each role have their own `HOME`, the thing is I don't have any idea how to make multiple `HOME` to make each role redirected to their own `HOME`

I think I must modify the generated auth by `laravel/ui` somewhere, but I have no idea how to modify it, I try to find the redirect path in the `LoginController` and it turns out the redirect path stored in `protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;`

and obviously I can't do something like:

```
public const HOME = '/admin';
public const HOME = '/guest';
public const HOME = '/receptionist';
```

Please enlighten me in the right way. I am new to laravel

Comment: Welcome to SO ... what version of Laravel are you using? but you could override the `authenticated` method

Comment: I use laravel 10, could you explain how to override the `authenticated` method?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70601180/laravel-7-redirecting-different-user-roles-to-different-view/70601547#70601547    something like that

Comment: It turns out the registration page was not redirected properly, and still redirected into RouteServiceProvider::HOME; I try to override authenticated method as you suggest, but it won't work in the RegisterController, only work for LoginController, and overriding redirectTo actually called, but the Auth::user() value is null.

Comment: It seems the Auth::user only filled after `return $next($request);`, but at first time redirect (from RegisterController) it still remain null. what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after looking into it, I found a solution by overriding the `redirectTo` method that seems to be used in the `trait RedirectsUsers`

the solution provided by @lagbox also works well (added in LoginController):

```php
/**
 * The user has been authenticated.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  mixed  $user
 * @return mixed
 */
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    if ($user->role === 'admin') {
        return redirect()->route('admin.analytic');
    } else if ($user->role === 'guest') {
        return redirect()->route('guest.reserve');
    } else if ($user->role === 'receptionist') {
        return redirect()->route('receptionist.booking_list');
    }
}
```

but I prefer this way personally (added in LoginController):

```php
protected function redirectTo() {
    switch (Auth::user()->role) {
        case 'admin':
            return route('admin.analytic');
        case 'receptionist':
            return route('receptionist.booking_list');
        case 'guest':
            return route('guest.reserve');
    }
}
```

Also to redirect back the user if logged in from `/login` or `/register` I need to update the `handle` method on `RedirectIfAuthenticated` Middleware:

```php
/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response)  $next
 */
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, string ...$guards): Response
{
    $guards = empty($guards) ? [null] : $guards;
    foreach ($guards as $guard) {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            switch (Auth::user()->role) {
                case 'admin':
                    return redirect()->route('admin.analytic');
                case 'receptionist':
                    return redirect()->route('receptionist.booking_list');
                case 'guest':
                    return redirect()->route('guest.reserve');
            }
        }
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

thanks to [@Thush-Fdo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66115625/laravel-user-login-based-on-roles-to-different-home-page) and @lagbox for helping me out!